# Optional field in Typescript interface

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

On an Angular 7 project I have the following Typescript interface:

```
export interface Request {
  expand: string;
  limit: number;
}
```

I then use it as follows:

```
let request: Request = { expand: 'address' };
```

I get an error because I am not setting `limit` ...

How can I make `limit` optional in the interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript 2.1 introduced [Partial type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick):

```
let request: Partial<Request> = { expand: 'address' };
```

Another way is to make the `limit` optional:

```
export interface Request {
  expand: string;
  limit?: number;
}
```